# How to avoid "Error in data[[txt]] : subscript out of bounds" error in predict.gam?

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a GAM model to a test dataset of two variables (x,y) and then predict the y variable using the x variable (I know this doesn’t make a lot of sense but it is part of bigger development and I am testing something). Building the gam model works but when I try to do the prediction it gives an error: “Error in data[[txt]] : subscript out of bounds” and I don’t understand what is the problem. If it managed to build the model with the gam function it should be able to run the predict.gam as well.

Thank you!

```r
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

# create dataframe
x = seq(0, 20, by = 0.5)
y = dnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x))
df = cbind.data.frame(x, y)

# fit the data
gam_mod <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = df, method = "REML")

# make prediction with the model using the x-value
pred <-predict.gam(gam_mod, newdata = df[, 1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `df[,1]` you are passing an unnamed vector to `predict.gam`. It needs a data frame with a column called `x`, otherwise it doesn't understand what you're trying to do.

You could instead do

```r
pred <- predict.gam(gam_mod, newdata = df[1])
```

And get the result you are looking for.

Note though, that by default, `predict` already uses the original data frame for `newdata`, and the `predict` method will select `predict.gam` automatically, so actually you need only do:

```
pred <- predict(gam_mod)

pred
#>          1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
#> 0.01638989 0.01900049 0.02165551 0.02440705 0.02729973 0.03035588 0.03356908 
#>          8          9         10         11         12         13         14 
#> 0.03690525 0.04030967 0.04371685 0.04706036 0.05027996 0.05332468 0.05615203 
#>         15         16         17         18         19         20         21 
#> 0.05872438 0.06100479 0.06295412 0.06453086 0.06569400 0.06640812 0.06664904 
#>         22         23         24         25         26         27         28 
#> 0.06640812 0.06569400 0.06453086 0.06295412 0.06100479 0.05872438 0.05615203 
#>         29         30         31         32         33         34         35 
#> 0.05332468 0.05027996 0.04706036 0.04371685 0.04030967 0.03690525 0.03356908 
#>         36         37         38         39         40         41 
#> 0.03035588 0.02729973 0.02440705 0.02165551 0.01900049 0.01638989
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is simply an issue of predict.gam needing to identify predictors by name (even in a univariate regression like this), and your subsetting drops the column name and reduces to a vector. If you subset like this (no comma), the column name is kept and you're good

```
pred <- predict.gam(gam_mod, newdata = df[1])
```